# How to access Form1 Function from Form2 without creating new Form();

Tags: c#, forms, function

I am newbie for C#

As the question I facing right now:

```
public void snz_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

//beside than this?
Form1 fs = new Form1();
fs.Snooze();

        }
```

Is that anyway other than using Form1 fs = new Form1() which create another new form before i can access fs.Snooze() ?? because this will make my apps appear 2 Form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access an existing instance of Form1, you need to make that instance available to Form2 somehow.

The common pattern is to provide a constructor for Form2 that takes an instance of Form1 as a parameter and stores that instance e.g. as a field or property.

```
private Form1 form1;
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1 = form1;
}
```

Then when constructing an instance of Form2

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(someExistingForm1Instance);
```